# Ruby unit testing - access test result (success/failure)?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, minitest, ruby-2.2

I'm using Ruby 2.2. I need to run a unit test and get information if it succeeded or failed. I'm browsing through docs of both test-unit and minitest (suggested gems for unit testing in Ruby 2.2) but I can't seem to find a method that would return or store somewhere information about the test result.

All I need is information whether the test failed/succeeded, and I need to access it from the level of Ruby. I imagine I would have to use a specific method to run the test - so far, I was only able to run a single test by running the test file, not by invoking any method.

Maybe it's just my poor knowledge of Ruby, anyway I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You want to run the tests programmatically? I mean, normally test pass/fail is reported to either a file, the console, or both.

Comment: I would prefer to access it on the level of Ruby. If that's not possible, then file - but I guess that would be in text form, like the result on console? I need to prepare statistics about the number of tests failed, I would prefer to ommit parsing such output. I don't know how to save result to the file either.

Comment: It sounds like you might want to consider an existing CI solution to avoid duplicating what they already do, but YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can run the tests using Ruby's ability to run shell command and return results.

Here is an example for [test-unit](https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit):

```
test_output = `ruby test.rb --runner console --verbose=progress`

failed_tests = test_output.chomp.split('').count('F')
passed_tests = test_output.chomp.split('').count('.')

puts "P: #{passed_tests}, F: #{failed_tests}"
```

We are using `--verbose=progress` option so that we get minimum output.  It will look something like below:

```
.F...F
```

We count number of `F` to figure out how many tests failed.
For about test output, the sample program will print:

```
P: 4, F: 2
```

Comment: Thanks! This is not how I imagined it, but it seems to do the trick, so a big thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `passed?` method:
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/minitest/unit/rdoc/MiniTest/Unit/TestCase.html#method-i-passed-3F
Not sure if it's still available in the latest versions of Ruby, so please check that before using.